# SQL Developer doesn't recognize right outer join ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

When I try to run the below query in SQL developer, query throws ORA-00905: missing keyword exception. SQL Developer does not recognize "right" and "join" keywords.

I know this error is caused by earlier versions of oracle sql but I cannot update the version. Could you re-write the statement in order to SQL developer to understand?

```
SELECT R,
       S.ATT1,
       S.ATT2,
       S.ATT3,
       S.ATT4
  FROM SHELL S
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN S.ROUTE as R
```

Comment: if you look at your code in sqldev, you can see we put a grammar warning on the R, and if you mouse over that you can see we are getting confused by the keyword 'AS'...so it's not the RIGHT OUTER JOIN causing your problem, it's an incorrect form of using a table alias - just remove the 'as'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong syntax. Try something like this:

```
select r.*, s.att1, s.att2, s.att3, s.att4
from shell s right outer join route r
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're missing the name of the table you're joining in your RIGHT OUTER JOIN, and then you need an ON clause. Also, you can't use `AS` when specifying a table alias - you should use `YOUR_TABLE r`, not `YOUR_TABLE AS r`. Perhaps you meant something like

```
select r ,s.att1, s.att2, s.att3, s.att4
  from shell  s
  right outer join YOUR_TABLE_HERE r
    ON r.ROUTE = s.route
```